# how to redirect out of a wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, web, header

I have a wordpress site, where after use logs in, I want them to redirect to different site.  How can i do this in wordpress?  setting the php header function( header( "Location: http://www.somesite.com" )  ) didn't work, it said headers were already set in header.php file.  So basically how do i redirect via wordpress?

Does wordpress have it's own re direct function, where i can use it to redirect safely out of a wordpress site?  I have no idea what else to do, so please help me, thanks.

Comment: where in your code do you do the redirect? (as in, at what point.. inside a page template, etc etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal pages, you can use `wp_redirect` (see [Function Reference/wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect))

```
<?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

To allow redirection to other sites, add the following to `functions.php` (replacing 'other' with your values):

```
function my_allowed_redirect_hosts($allowed) {
    $allowed[] = 'other.com';
    $allowed[] = 'www.other.com';
    return $allowed;
}
add_filter('allowed_redirect_hosts','my_allowed_redirect_hosts');
```

Normally, if there is a `redirect_to` querystring value on the login page's URL, it will attempt to redirect to that location after authenticating.

To change where the login will redirect users regardless of the `redirect_to` querystring value, again add to `functions.php` (replacing the location with your values):

```
function custom_login_redirect() {
  return 'http://www.other.com/Home/Authenticated';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect');
```

For logging out and redirectng to another site, you can then use something like:

```
<a href="<?=wp_logout_url( "http://other.com/Account/LogOff" )?>">Log Off</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
//chage the redirection url for login
add_filter('login_redirect','my_redirect_to_my_site',100,3);
function my_redirect_to_my_site($redirect_to_calculated,$redirect_url_specified,$user){
   return "http://google.com";//where you want to redirect ,change with that

}


//add the domain to allowed hosts list for redirection
add_filter('allowed_redirect_hosts','my_allowed_redirect_hosts');
function my_allowed_redirect_hosts($allowed_hosts){
 $allowed_hosts[]='google.com'; //add the other domain to allowed hosts where to redirect
 return $allowed_hosts;
}
```

Make sure to add your host name(where you want to redirect in the allowed_hosts list). you can put this code in functiions.php of your theme and it will redirect the user on login.
Hope that helps :)